# Is there a website on how to store specific foods?

Tags: websites

I ask if there are websites which explain how to store/preserve (in the fridge, freezer, out) all kind of foodstuff.   Examples: eggs, milk, meat, specific fruits, specific vegetables, etc.
This [book](http://www.librarything.com/work/book/73834372) provides such descriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resource we generally use here on Seasoned Advice is [stilltasty.com](http://stilltasty.com).

Feel free to edit this answer to include other resources.

Comment: that is quite good

Answer (score -1):

I've done a lot of searching over the years, but I've never been able to find a single website that has everything. Whenever I have a question I just use a search engine and use whatever method seems most popular in the search results.